# ProgressBar turns visible after work is done

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I made a simple sudoku-solver app in Android Studio that tries to solve any given N x M sudoku. For boards of size 4 x 4 this can take a couple of seconds, so I want an indeterminate ProgressBar to run while the calculations are being done.

When the user presses the button, `SolveSudoku()` runs. First it sets the ProgressBar visible, runs the solving logic, then hides it again. Problem is that the ProgressBar only displays after the sudoku is solved and printed to screen. How can I fix this?

**activity_sudoku.xml**

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:indeterminate="true"
    android:elevation="8dp"/>
```

**SudokuActivity.java**

```
private ProgressBar progBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

public void SolveSudoku(View v){
    progBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    try{
        //Solving logic
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        //Error handling for invalid inputs, etc..
    }
    finally{
        progBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
}
```

If I comment the codeline in the finally-clause, the spinner just keeps spinning after I've gotten the result. But as it is for now, the ProgressBar doesn't show up at all. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: ProgressBar works well on AsyncTask. Usually operation that takes time to finish should be put inside the AsyncTask.

Answer (score 0):

The style of the ProgressBar you chose `?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge` is a spinner.

If you want both a spinner and a progress bar you should add 2 separate ProgressBar views in your xml, and style them differently.

In order to style a ProgressBar as an actual loading progress bar, you can use `?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal`

This is an example layout with both a spinner and a progress bar:

```
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/spinner_progress_bar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/actual_progress_bar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/spinner_progress_bar"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        />
```

Now, if you want a progress bar, you should update its progress manually.
Here is an example snippet that updates the progress bar from 0 to full in a second.

```
        final ProgressBar progressBar = findViewById(R.id.actual_progress_bar);
        progressBar.setMax(100);

        new Thread(
                () -> {
                    try {
                        int a = 0;
                        while (a <= 100) {
                            final int weakA = a;
                            runOnUiThread(() -> progressBar.setProgress(weakA));
                            a++;
                            Thread.sleep(10);
                        }
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                    }
                }
        ).start();
```

The idea is: You should calculate the progress of your algorythm yourself and set it accordingly. And remember to always call `ProgressBar.setProgress(int)` (or any view specific method for that matter) within a runOnUiThread() method, otherwise you'll get an error.

Comment: I just want a spinner progressbar (indeterminate). I don't want the horizontal one where I set the value, since I don't know how much work is already done (or is remaining).

Comment: Then you can just replace ```progBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);``` with ``` runOnUiThread(() -> progBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE));``` and ```progBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);``` with ```runOnUiThread(() -> progBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE));```